# How would I go about interfacing the raspberry pi and arduino?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I want to do a project where I control motors, and the arduino seems ideal for that. However, I'm going to need to do quite a bit of processing on the back end first. Connecting the arduino to a computer isn't an option, because it has to be quite mobile. Does anyone have any experience controlling arduino with raspberry pi?

Comment: Also see  [Including a RaspberryPi within a robot... Does this allow for a "universal API"?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/609), and  [Is a Raspberry Pi processor powerful enough for a mobile chatbot?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1413), and  [Good Microcontrollers/SOCs for a Robotics Project](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/4),

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* higgs241, but whilst it is probably a good design decision to use a microcontroller for low level control and a general purpose CPU for task level, your question as it stands is not a good fit for a stack exchange site. Please read [ask] and [about] for more information on how to ask [*practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face* since *chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site*](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).